# Open dial page on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

my application needs to open the default dialing page of windows phone.

Any idea how to do this ?

I'm using windows phone 7.1 sdk.

Answer (score 3):

You can't open the default dialing page.  You can instigate a phone call task which will then open the dialing page.

```
    PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
    phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "2065550123";
    phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Spanish restaurant";
    phoneCallTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create page for get All Contacts.Like page Contact in your windows phone. 
With this, user can select contact for phonning.